# Understanding HttpSessions and Authentication

Tags: jakarta-ee, cookies, httpsession

I have been working with a J2EE application that uses form-based authentication. I understand HttpSession objects, and the different use cases that they have for storing user data (shopping carts for example), since http is a stateless protocol.

When a client makes a request (to, for example, add something to their cart), a session is created, if not present, and a cart is either created, or updated in the session. When the response is sent back to the client, an HTTP cookie called JSessionID is a part of the response, and that cookie is stored in the browser. So when subsequent requests are made to the server (assuming the cookies have not been cleared in the browser, or the server has not been restarted, or the session hasn't timed out) the session can be located, and that is what gives the 'statefulness' attribute to an otherwise stateless http request/response protocol.

My questions are:

1)When a user logs into an application that uses form based authentication, is a session automatically created?

2)If not, what has to happen for the user to actually be logged out, since there is no session to invalidate?

More generally, I'm really trying to understand whether there is a connection between a users HttpSession and the user being 'logged in' as far as form based authentication is concerned. Can a user be logged in and not have a session.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question has historically been platform dependent. WebSphere for example did not require a session for the user to be authenticated, but required the use of a WAS specific servlet call in order to "logout" a user.

This was finally fixed in the Servlet 3.1 specification (Java EE 7) when [HttpServletRequest.logout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#logout()) was added.